# Rules for Classic World of Darkness Abomination?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, werewolf-the-apocalypse

Were there ever rules published for Abominations? They were suburban legends, never meant to be, at least not as PCs, but I'm curious what mechanical and narrative elements defined them. I felt like cWod did a good job balancing power with consequences, sometimes the counter-balance for character sheet power was in-game hardships.

I would love reference to a book or article, paraphrased for rpg.SE if possible, otherwise the most balanced and compelling house rule will get the answer vote.

Comment: @Jadasc It seems like there's enough distinction for cWoD to merit it's own tag… perhaps more-so with the success of the 20th Anniversary games. Can you explain why one WoD tag covers them all?

Comment: There was a plan to do so about a year ago, but it seems to have been lost in the shuffle, and the tag has thrived nevertheless. Here's the relevant metathread. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/shall-we-review-the-various-world-of-darkness-tags-use. My recommendation is to draw mod attention to the old plan rather than go through and retag.

Comment: @Jadasc thank you for the help, still learning the ropes here. I got to 300 rep and my eyes widened at the prospect of making a new tag, didn't realize what I was stepping into. ;)

Comment: No worries -- and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do take a look at [the Abomination entry](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Abomination) of Wikia's unofficial White Wolf Wiki, if you haven't done so yet. It has a summary of rules, as well as references to the books those rules are summarized from (primarily the book [Under A Blood Red Moon](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Under_a_Blood_Red_Moon), a crossover product for o/cWoD Werewolf and Vampire, which had an entire appendix dedicated to abominations.)

I know link rot could kill this A in the (very) long run, but I'm not going to quote the Wiki anyway, because I'd have to lift practically everything from there, which I think neither they nor rpg.SE would be happy about. (Mods, correct me if I'm wrong, please.)

You might also want check out certain answers to this question (of mine): [In-game reason for no multiple supernatural templates in nWoD](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/in-game-reason-for-no-multiple-supernatural-templates-in-nwod). Even though I'm asking about the nWoD, people touch upon the oWoD as well, for obvious reasons, and with rather interesting content.

Comment: The Wikia link is good, thanks, and I did read your question about template bashing, but I wanted to keep the question cWoD specific, since I know little about the nWoD and am not in a position to pursue it. I'll give the question a couple more days to see if anyone has house rules, if not the answer goes to you.

Comment: In that same link you have the books in which are rules for abominations (at least some of them, maybe there are others). Just note that in UaBRM rules are a bit more permissive, so you should check both UaBRM and the Storyteller Handbook to see which fit you the better. The main difference is that in revised abominations suffer permanent Harano, which halves their stats.